# How to use correctly Myanmar font in SQL 'where' clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

select * from item where Item_type like 'ဆဆဆ';
[This is the data that I want to retrieve using Myanmar font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7qFi.png)

Comment: I dont' think there's a collation for Myanmar for SQL server... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143508.aspx.  so then "how to use a language which doesn't support collation? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143508.aspx  So I think that means ?  Interesting paper: http://my.duniakitab.com/ThanLwinSoft/ThanLwinSoft/MyanmarUnicode/Sorting/

Comment: Thanks I found an answer!

Comment: Select * from item where Item_type like N'ဆဆဆ';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select * from item where Item_type like N'ဆဆဆ';

The data type is nvarchar type so ! Sorry for my bad language.